# C# LINQ - Loop through list to get Data

Tags: linq, model, webapi

Would you please show me how to put a comma delimited string with email addresses (`abc@aa.com, def@ab.com, ghi@ac.com,...`) into LINQ list then loop through each email address and go to SQL database to get name, address, phone number and return these back.  EmailList below contains `abc@aa.com`, `def@ab.com`, `ghi@ac.com`,..

```
public class PersonalInfo
{
   public string firstname {get; set;}
   public string lastname {get; set;}
   public string address {get; set;}
   public string phonenumber {get; set;}
}

public PersonalInfo GetInfo(string EmailList)
{
    ....
}
```

I can do the part to get info from SQL table.  Just need help to loop through EmailList, call method to get data then return the data back to PersonalInfo.

Comment: Since `GetInfo()` accepts a list of email addresses, should the return type be a collection of `PersonalInfo` objects instead of just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a string that you want to break apart on a particular character, you can use the `Split()` method. The caveat is that if you don't have a clear delimiting character you might split something you don't intend to. The comma is not commonly found in email addresses so this should be fine. The `Split()` method will return an array of strings.

The next caveat is that "abc@aa.com, def@ab.com" will leave a space character before the "def" of the second email address. To remove these you can use the `Trim()` method of a string. `Trim()` will remove whitespace from the start and end of a string. `Trim()` is non-destructive so you need to store the results.

The below method uses split to get an array with each entry being an email address. Then the `Select()` linq method is used to iterate each email address and return the Trim() result. Now the `emails` variable is an `IEnumerable<string>` with each string being an email that can be used to do the database lookup. I changed the return type on the Function to be a `List<PersonalInfo>` as I assume you are wanting to look up each person and return all results.

```
public List<PersonalInfo> GetInfo(string EmailList)
{
    List<PersonalInfo> output = new();
    var emails = EmailLIst.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());

    foreach (var email in emails)
    {
        // table lookup
        PersonalInfo info = GetFromTable(email);
        output.Add(info);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: My only suggestion would be using LINQ to DB with `Contains` on `emails` might be a better way to return all the info at once.

Comment: Can you show me how to do LINQ to DB with Contains on emails as you suggested?

Comment: @AmandaCortes - Nothing in your post indicates how you are accessing the database. Are you using Entity Framework? My best guess would be something like this:

`databaseContext.PersonalInfos.Where(pi => emails.Contains(pi.Address)).ToList();`

This assumes that you have followed the code above to get the list of emails in an array, and that PersonalInfo is a table in your database, and the Address property is the email address. At best, this gets you an idea of how to apply the concept to your own situation.